# Controlling order of functions in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have something like this:

```
final JButton btnGenerate = new JButton("Generate Keys");
        btnGenerate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                //On click, Generate Keys
                toConsole("[RSA] Generating a pair of keys, this can take several minutes...");
                GenerateKeys();
                toConsole("[RSA] Done");
                btnGenerate.setEnabled(false);
                btnConnect.setEnabled(true);
            }
        });
```

toConsole:

```
public void toConsole (String s) {
        chatArea.append(s + "\n");
    }
```

GenerateKey:

```
public void GenerateKeys(){
        try {                               
            KeyPairGenerator keyGen = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
            keyGen.initialize(4096);
            KeyPair keyPair = keyGen.genKeyPair();          
            publicKey = keyPair.getPublic().getEncoded();
            privateKey = keyPair.getPrivate().getEncoded();             
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }
```

So, when the user press a button, I am trying to generate a pair of RSA key with the length of 4096, but before this I want to append to my TextArea this:

"[RSA] Generating a pair of keys, this can take several minutes..."

When I run the program and click on that button, nothing appear on the TextArea, instead the program start to generate the pair of keys, and after that it print the text on the TextArea. There is something wrong in my code? I called toConsole() first, and then GenerateKeys()...

Comment: Likely, you're doing the whole thing on the EDT, which will freeze your GUI until the EDT is able to process events again.  Use a [background task.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Comment: Ok, i will try it. Just for curiosity, why i need to do this even if the append command is before the GenerateKey function?

Comment: See my comment:  "will freeze your GUI"

Comment: Your GUI only updates when you *return* from your handling code.  It doesn't update as you go.

Answer (score 2):

You must understand that Swing manages every event in the same thread that it uses in order to repaint the GUI elements.

A possible way to decouple both things would be to enclose your lengthy tasks into a SwingWorker.  This is a task you can throw into a Swing-managed threadpool, that is even able to update the GUI along with its progress.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html

Another possible way would be just to pop a new Thread with your task and make updates to your GUI from there by using `invokeLater`

http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/threads/invokelater.shtml

This would be the easiest one.  Hope this is useful!